# Changing the order of arguments in ruby sprintf

Tags: ruby, printf

Is it possible to change the order of parameters to `sprintf`?

like `sprintf(" this is %arg[2] test %arg[1]" , arg1, arg2)`

I need to dynamically change the order of the arguments so is that  possible with `sprintf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
irb(main):007:0> arg1 = 'foo'
=> "foo"
irb(main):008:0> arg2 = 'bar'
=> "bar"
irb(main):009:0> sprintf("%3$0.3f this is %2$s test %1$s" , arg1, arg2, Math::PI)
=> "3.142 this is bar test foo"
```

The format is `%N$fmt` where N indicates the ordinal position of the argument, and `fmt` is what you would put after the `%` sign when using `sprintf` normally.